# Spring MVC request Mapping Class level

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have made a small spring mvc app. In my controller i have 2 methods which returns the names of the jsp files in the web-inf folder. 
Now the application works perfectly, but if i try to add a url path it doesn't work.

What i mean is something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/start")  //if add this it doesn't work
public class SalesController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
public String sayGreeting(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greetingMsg", "Hello Spring");
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public String getHello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Yo man");
    return "hello";
     }
 }
```

Here is my servletConfig  configuration

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

If i give the path "myApplicationName"/start/greeting it give error. But if i remove start it works.

What seems to be the problem here?

Thank you

Update:

Below is my web.xml configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you embed your web.xml?

Comment: @px5x2 ok i have added it

Comment: @FranMontero it gives a 404 error.

Comment: I see no problem in your code. Is it really compiled and deployed?

Comment: Yes it compiles successfully as well and it goes to the default page as well.

Comment: In my apps, i have  `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` , Could you try that?

Comment: I think that should work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add ***/*.html*** in your URL Pattern:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param> </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Still i get the error. Thanks for the reply though :)